# Работа с переменными JS в PHP файле

Tags: javascript, php, переменные

Возник очень идиотский вопрос.

Ситуация следующая, имеется php файл, для обработки массива. В один момент пришлось прибегнуть к js библиотеке для расчетов. Ввиду кое-каких обстоятельств, приходится всё делать только через php. Соответственно библиотека подключена через echo, как и вызывается скрипт:

```
<?php
  echo '<script src="proj4.js"></script>
       ';
  $json = file_get_contents('data.json');
  $json_data = json_decode($json,true);

  for($i=0; $i<count($json_data['features']); $i++){

    $ost = $json_data['features'][$i];

    $c_x = $ost['geometry']['coordinates'][0];
    $c_y = $ost['geometry']['coordinates'][1];

    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
            msk = "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=55.66666666667 +lon_0=37.5 +k=1 +x_0=16.098 +y_0=14.512 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=316.151,78.924,589.650,-1.57273,2.69209,2.34693,8.4507 +units=m +no_defs";
            mks_coords = proj4("WGS84",msk,['.$c_x.','.$c_y.']);
          </script>
         ';
  }

?>
```

Вопрос возникает в следующем: Как передать в этом же файле переменную из js в php (в данном случае msk_coords)?

P.S. Передача в адресную строку через location.hash не подойдет, слишком большой массив данных.
P.P.S. Самому стыдно

Comment: [Передача значений переменных](http://codeharmony.ru/materials/129) из JavaScript в PHP и обратно.

Comment: "Как передать в этом же файле переменную из js в php" - чтобы что?

Comment: Это банальный способ через GET с перезагрузкой страницы и POST с отправкой формы. Вы предлагаете мне более 10 тысяч значений через адресную строку/форму передавать в php?

Comment: Получили значение через js в переменную b. Требуется переменную b записать в, допустим, переменную $c, для последующей работы с данными. В этом же файле.

Comment: Покажите больше кода. Приведите пример.

Comment: Добавил кусок кода в пост.

Comment: яваскрипт POST'ом либо через XHR либо через ajax(Другого не дано, предварительно завернув в json) На стороне ПХП получить  $_POST['переменая'] и распарсить json

Comment: не надо перезагружать страницу, пошлите через XNR или AJAX

Comment: @SlyFox метод `POST` не?

Comment: в какое место "этого же файла" Вы хотите передать переменную `mks_coords`, и что это за объект?

Comment: msk_coords - это массив из двух координат вида [xxxxx.xxxxx, yyyyy.yyyyy]. Требуется принять значение переменной в php дальше по коду в текущий цикл (после echo), без перезагрузки страницы.

Comment: @SlyFox Я что-то подобное подозревал. Так это не работает. PHP - на одном компьютере, JS - на другом, за тысячи километров. Вам нужна библиотека для преобразования координат на PHP.